# Let $f,g$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ and $f(r)=g(r)$ if $r∈\mathbb{Q}$, is it true that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x∈\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ and $f(r)=g(r)$ if $r∈\mathbb{Q}$, is it true that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x∈\mathbb{R}$

I think it should be true, but I have no idea how to prove it, anyone could help me? Thanks.

Comment: Take $x\notin \Bbb Q$, and $r_n\in\Bbb Q$ such that $r_n\to x$. Then $f(r_n)=g(r_n)\to ??$

Comment: the set $\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed, and since it contains $\Bbb Q$ it is also dense, hence it must be equal to $\Bbb R$.